# Vue 3 Append Component to the DOM: Best Practice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I would like to dynamically create a component in my Vue 3 app that I have in an SFC, and append it to the DOM. I am using `<script setup>` style components, which is yet another wrinkle.

This seems unnecessarily hard.

Here's more or less what I want to do:

1. Fetch some data. Got that.
2. Make an instance of my Vue Component: Foo.vue.
3. Hand it that data as a prop.
4. Append it to the DOM where I want it.

The problem is that I can't do <component :is="Foo:> in the template because I don't know where it will be until long after the template is rendered.

Is there a best practice for this? A simple example some kind soul can provide would be hugely appreciated.

I cannot make heads or tails out of the Vue docs half the time. Sorry, hate to say it, but they are pretty opaque to newbies to Vue, and make me feel dumb.

Here's some pretend code illustrating what I want to do

```
import Foo from "../components/Foo.vue"

function makeAFoo(p, data){
// instantiate my Foo.vue (not sure how to do this inline), and pass it the data it needs
let foo = new Foo(data); // if only it were this simple, right?
// Append it to p (which is an HTML Element)
p.appendChild(foo)
}
```

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#the-root-component

Comment: How is this helpful? (Serious question.) I am already in a Vue app, but my makeAFoo function wants to append a programmatically instantiated Vue SFC and append it to the existing DOM.

Comment: How is this helpful? It explains **the only way** how to mount Vue component into DOM

Comment: Could the Teleport feature be something to consider: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/teleport.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Option 1: `createVNode(component, props)` and `render(vnode, container)`

**Creating:** Use `createVNode()` to create a `VNode` of a component definition (e.g., imported SFC from `*.vue`) with props, which could be passed to `render()` to render it on a given container element.

**Destroying:** Calling `render(null, container)` [destroys the `VNode`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/5aa425580808d0588aef12ead81c91f7147e1042/packages/runtime-core/src/renderer.ts#L2316) attached to the container. This should be called as cleanup when the parent component unmounts (via [`unmounted` lifecycle hook](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#lifecycle-hooks)).

```js
// renderComponent.js
import { createVNode, render } from 'vue'

export default function renderComponent({ el, component, props, appContext }) {
  let vnode = createVNode(component, props)
  vnode.appContext = { ...appContext }
  render(vnode, el)

  return () => {
    // destroy vnode
    render(null, el)
    vnode = undefined
  }
}
```

**Caveat:** This approach relies on internal methods (`createVNode` and `render`), which could be refactored or removed in a future release.

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-instantiate-component-v8ecmy?file=src%2FrenderComponent.js)

### Option 2: `createApp(component, props)` and `app.mount(container)`

**Creating:** Use [`createApp()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#createapp), which returns an [application instance](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#creating-an-application-instance). The instance has [`mount()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#mount), which can be used to render the component on a given container element.

**Destroying:** The application instance has [`unmount()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#unmount) to destroy the app and component instances. This should be called as cleanup when the parent component unmounts (via [`unmounted` lifecycle hook](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#lifecycle-hooks)).

```js
// renderComponent.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'

export default function renderComponent({ el, component, props, appContext }) {
  let app = createApp(component, props)
  Object.assign(app._context, appContext) // must use Object.assign on _context
  app.mount(el)

  return () => {
    // destroy app/component
    app?.unmount()
    app = undefined
  }
}
```

**Caveat:** This approach creates an application instance for each component, which could be non-trivial overhead if there's a need to instantiate many components simultaneously in the document.

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-instantiate-component-tj3jpg?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue)

### Example usage

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onUnmounted, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
import renderComponent from './renderComponent'

const { appContext } = getCurrentInstance()
const container = ref()
let counter = 1
let destroyComp = null

onUnmounted(() => destroyComp?.())

const insert = async () => {
  destroyComp?.()
  destroyComp = renderComponent({
    el: container.value,
    component: (await import('@/components/HelloWorld.vue')).default
    props: {
      key: counter,
      msg: 'Message ' + counter++,
    },
    appContext,
  })
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="insert">Insert component</button>
  <div ref="container"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: The dynamic component created by `render` cannot be inspected by VueDevtools v6.0.0-beta.20 so far.

Comment: In case someone is puzzled by destroyComp?.() look up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860763/what-does-return-local-do-in-this-closure

Answer (score 3):

[@tony19's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491554/595152) is good, but you can do this much simpler with Vue 3:

```
import { render, h } from 'vue'
import Foo from "../components/Foo.vue"

function makeAFoo(p, data) {
  // instantiate my Foo.vue, and pass it the props it needs
  const vueComponent = h(Foo, data);
  
  // Append it to p (which is an HTML Element)
  render(vueComponent, p)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. However, when implementing this approach, I came across another issue, which is that the component being rendered doesn't re-render when its props change. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: @AchrafFAWZI for rerender, you need to do remove the component again: `render(null, p);` and then rerender it, by calling it again: `makeAFoo(p, {...})` --- you maybe need `await nextTick()` in between, if that does not work!

Answer (score 0):

A more simple approach is to use v-if or v-for.

Instead of dealing directly with components you can deal with the state of components and let Vue reactivity do the magic

Here is an example that appends a component dynamically(Toast) while only manipulating the state of the component

**Toast.vue file** : the v-for is reactive here, whenever a new error is added to the errors's object, it will be rendered

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { watch } from 'vue';
import { ref, onUpdated } from 'vue';
import { Toast } from 'bootstrap';

const props = defineProps({
  errors: { type: Array, default: () => [] },
});

onUpdated(() => {
  const hiddenToasts = props.errors.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.show != true;
  });
  hiddenToasts.forEach(function (error) {
    var errorToast = document.getElementById(error.id);
    var toast = new Toast(errorToast);
    toast.show();
    error.show = true;
    errorToast.addEventListener('hidden.bs.toast', function () {
      const indexOfObject = props.errors.findIndex((item) => {
        return item.id === error.id;
      });
      if (indexOfObject !== -1) {
        props.errors.splice(indexOfObject, 1);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
<script lang="ts">
const TOASTS_MAX = 5;
export function push(array: Array, data): Array {
  if (array.length == TOASTS_MAX) {
    array.shift();
    array.push(data);
  } else {
    array.push(data);
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div
    ref="container"
    class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3"
    style="z-index: 11"
  >
    <div
      v-for="item in errors"
      v-bind:id="item.id"
      class="toast fade opacity-75 bg-danger"
      role="alert"
      aria-live="assertive"
      aria-atomic="true"
      data-bs-delay="15000"
    >
      <div class="toast-header bg-danger">
        <strong class="me-auto text-white">Error</strong>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="toast"
          aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="toast-body text-white error-body">{{ item.msg }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**ErrorTrigger.vue**: here we push an error to the errors's object whenever a click happens

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue';
import toast from './Toast.vue';
import { push } from './Toast.vue';

const count = ref(0);
const state = reactive({ errors: [] });

function pushError(id: int) {
  push(state.errors, { id: id, msg: 'Error message ' + id });
}
</script>

<template>
  <toast :errors="state.errors"></toast>

  <button type="button" @click="pushError('toast' + count++)">
    Error trigger: {{ count }}
  </button>
</template>
```

complete example here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-mcjgkl

Comment: In the linked project v-if or v-for is nowhere used. It's preferrable to provide a working example here as a 'static' answer rather than depending on some referenced projects.

Comment: done, hope it help now

Answer (score 0):

The [mount-vue-component](https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component) package provides a helper function that uses Option 1 in @tony19's answer.

One caveat: if the component is defined in a `.vue` file and only created programmatically, you may need to import and register it.  Otherwise tree shaking may remove its template, resulting in an empty component being inserted on prod.  (This problem seems to principally affect Vue + Vite.)

For example:

```js
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";
const app = createApp(App).use(router);
app.component("MyComponent", MyComponent);
```